# PHP Check Create Folder File Hierarchy

Tags: php, file

Hello My Fellow Seniors~~

I have been thingking and trying to tell PHP to CHECK Folder and CHECK File (if already exist alert user! if not then make that Folder / File) .

Almost forget to tell, that I use XAMPP Localhost Webbase to get users datas and that datas will be place in one of my pc that act like server for my other pcs.

Also I have been trying to make that File have some attributes or tags such as Who make that file, who edit that file, how many time that file have been edited, and other tags that could make the time for searching a file get lesser. Hmmm other tags or attribute may come from the user inputs.

Thank you for your helps ~~

Just in any case, here the folder scheme that I made (as img) :

[My Scheme of folders and files hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUxbk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

PHP will automatically create directory's when needed.
here is a small script to guide you:

```
<?php
$path = "";
if (file_exists("./path/of/file")){
    echo "Alert user notification here";
}
else{
    $myfile = fopen("./path/of/file/newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "Cool text file here :D";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Comment: Than you for your respon senior ~~ But what I want is PHP create a folder and its name base on Years e.g 2020, Months name e.g January, February, soon, and base on some categories, just like in the picture that added. Out of all I pay my respect for your kind, thank you.